# UITextView dataDetectorTypes can't detect http://t.co/ links?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, hyperlink

```
    theTweet = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 225, 65)] autorelease];
    theTweet.text = [[tweets objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"text"];
    theTweet.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
    [tweetView addSubview:theTweet];
```

[[tweets objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"text"]; contains a link with http://t.co/###### but it doesn't seem like the UITextView is detecting http://t.co links. Do I need to use a UIWebView instead?

Comment: are you missing theTweet.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink; ?

Comment: already in. still not working.

Answer (score 11):

One thing I've noticed is that in order for UITextViews to recognize links, you need to **set selectable to YES**. Example:

```
self.bodyTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:myFrame];
[self.bodyTextView setEditable:NO];
//this is the key
[self.bodyTextView setSelectable:YES];
[self.bodyTextView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink];
[self.bodyTextView setAttributedText:myAttributedText];
```

Comment: is there any possible way.. by which we can keep data detectors ON but selectable off? In my current code, i dont want to allow user to select text, but wanted to detect links and allow to click them.

Comment: Out of the box, I don't think so, but here's an answer that talks about such a thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198299/uitextview-disable-selection-allow-links

Answer (score 3):

did you set: `theTweet.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink; ?`

Now that you added that, I tried this code:

```
    UITextView *theTweet;
theTweet = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 225, 65)];
theTweet.text = @"http://t.co/######";
theTweet.editable = NO;
theTweet.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
[myview addSubview:theTweet];
```

and it works fine with me.

The error must be somewhere else. (did you turn off editable too?)

Comment: yep, forgot to add that in the original post. still not working.

Comment: will double check on next build.

Comment: Make sure you're testing on device, not in simulator.

Comment: @Henning does this not work in the simulator?  Or is that just a general comment on how not to trust your simulator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set editable property NO

```
theTweet = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 225, 65)] autorelease];
theTweet.editable = NO; //add this line
theTweet.text = [[tweets objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"text"];
theTweet.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
[tweetView addSubview:theTweet];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe good to make extension so we don't have to memorize it...

```
@implementation UITextView (Extension)

- (instancetype)dataDetector :(UIDataDetectorTypes)types {
    self.dataDetectorTypes = types;
    if (types != UIDataDetectorTypeNone) self.selectable = true;
    return self;
}

@end
```