# How do i stop my ios app from opening a url when user taps on any link in the app?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to stop my app from opening a url that may be present in my textview when I populate it with the data I get from api.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198299/uitextview-disable-selection-allow-links

Comment: This is not what i want, i basically want to know when and what url my app is trying and make a decision whether we want to allow or not.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecked "`Link`" and "`Address`" flag to disable URLs which exist in `UItextview`, see the following.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
textView.dataDetectorTypes = []
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement [textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview) of the [UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate) you can control whether the URL should be opened or not.

Just return `false` if you don't want any URL to be handled:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```