# Disable 'Open link' from clipboard in Swift

Tags: swift, textview, uitextview

I need to disable url selection from my text view. I have set the data detector property to an empty array and set `func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {}` method to return false. But it's still showing 'open link' option in clipboard when selecting the text. How do I disable this in my text view?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1ixc.png)

Comment: did you check this textView.selectedTextRange = nil ??

Comment: Yes I tried that, but that is prohibiting me from editing the text view. I need to edit it, but don't have to open any urls from it

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54899719/how-do-i-stop-my-ios-app-from-opening-a-url-when-user-taps-on-any-link-in-the-ap

Comment: All of them are disabling the tap altogether